# Get struct by its pointer in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get information about the handles in a process from the `NtQuerySystemInformation()` function. I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <process.h>

#define SystemHandleInformation 0x10
#define SystemHandleInformationSize 1024 * 1024 * 2

using fNtQuerySystemInformation = NTSTATUS(WINAPI*)(
    ULONG SystemInformationClass,
    PVOID SystemInformation,
    ULONG SystemInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
);

typedef struct _DEVICE_OBJECT* PDEVICE_OBJECT;
typedef struct _PVPB* PVPB;
typedef struct _KEVENT* PKEVENT;
typedef struct _IO_COMPLETION_CONTEXT* PIO_COMPLETION_CONTEXT;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
{
    USHORT UniqueProcessId;
    USHORT CreatorBackTraceIndex;
    UCHAR ObjectTypeIndex;
    UCHAR HandleAttributes;
    USHORT HandleValue;
    PVOID Object;
    ULONG GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO, * PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    ULONG NumberOfHandles;
    SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO Handles[1];
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, * PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS
{
    PVOID DataSectionObject;
    PVOID SharedCacheMap;
    PVOID ImageSectionObject;
} SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS, * PSECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS;

typedef struct _FILE_OBJECT
{
    SHORT Type;
    SHORT Size;
    PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject;
    PVPB Vpb;
    PVOID FsContext;
    PVOID FsContext2;
    PSECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS SectionObjectPointer;
    PVOID PrivateCacheMap;
    LONG FinalStatus;
    struct _FILE_OBJECT *RelatedFileObject;
    UCHAR LockOperation;
    UCHAR DeletePending;
    UCHAR ReadAccess;
    UCHAR WriteAccess;
    UCHAR DeleteAccess;
    UCHAR SharedRead;
    UCHAR SharedWrite;
    UCHAR SharedDelete;
    ULONG Flags;
    UNICODE_STRING FileName;
    LARGE_INTEGER CurrentByteOffset;
    ULONG Waiters;
    ULONG Busy;
    PVOID LastLock;
    PKEVENT Lock;
    PKEVENT Event;
    PIO_COMPLETION_CONTEXT CompletionContext;
    ULONG IrpListLock;
    LIST_ENTRY IrpList;
    PVOID FileObjectExtension;
} FILE_OBJECT, * PFILE_OBJECT;


int main() {
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    ULONG returnLenght = 0;
    fNtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation = (fNtQuerySystemInformation)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handleTableInformation = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, SystemHandleInformationSize);
    NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, handleTableInformation, SystemHandleInformationSize, &returnLenght);
    int PID = _getpid();

    for (int i = 0; i < handleTableInformation->NumberOfHandles; i++)
    {
        SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO handleInfo = (SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO)handleTableInformation->Handles[i];

        if (handleInfo.UniqueProcessId == PID && handleInfo.ObjectTypeIndex == 37)
        {
            printf_s("Handle 0x%x at 0x%p, PID: %x\n", handleInfo.HandleValue, handleInfo.Object, handleInfo.UniqueProcessId);

            PFILE_OBJECT fileObj = (PFILE_OBJECT)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 1024 * 1024 * 2);
            memcpy(&fileObj, &handleInfo.Object, sizeof(fileObj));
            printf_s("%d\n", fileObj->Type);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the `IF` condition, I'm checking the PID of `handleInfo` and whether the object type is 37, which means it's a file object (this is the correct index in Windows 10. In other OS's it may be different). In this `IF` block, I need to get the `PFILE_OBJECT` by its pointer stored in `handleInfo.Object`. But when I call the `memcpy()` function to assign this structure to a variable, I'm getting an `Access violation of reading location` error.

What am I doing wrong? How to access this structure? I need to get its Type, ReadAccess, WriteAccess, FileName, and so on.

Comment: You have no error checking. What happens if something fails? Perhaps your program doesn't have the privileges to do what it want to do?

Comment: Why are you copying a pointer with memcpy?  `fileObj` is a pointer to a FILE_OBJECT.  `&fileObj` is a pointer to your PFILE_OBJECT variable (which is just a pointer to a FILE_OBJECT).

Comment: you allocate memory  letting fileObject point to it, but then you overwrite the address of the filepointer in your memcpy statement, that is not right. Object is also a pointer so you should copy what it points to, not the pointer itself. Finally the tag C++ is wrong, it should read C

Comment: @AndersK
thanks for reply. but what is the correct way to do it? I'm really confused in C/C++ languages syntax

Comment: @AndersK it's not valid C, there's `#include <iostream>` and a `using`

Comment: Psychic debugging: you want `PFILE_OBJECT fileObj = (PFILE_OBJECT)handleInfo.Object;`, and don't need any `HeapAlloc` nor `memcpy`

Comment: You can't assign kernel memory from user mode in direct way

Comment: The thing I mostly like about C++ is the ability to write cross platform code. Questions like this make me really sad since it so clearly demonstrates how C++ can be abused to write very *non cross platform* code ☹️ Please don't write code like this.

Comment: @Caleth
I've tried this now. But anyway got "read access violation". It seems that I can't read kernel memory as RbMm mentioned

Comment: @JesperJuhl What C++ infrastructure would you suggest using instead here?

Comment: @IInspectable "What C++ infrastructure would you suggest using instead here" - Anything but OS specific libraries. Perhaps Qt, SFML, SDL, imgui or similar.

Comment: @JesperJuhl None of those libraries can do this.

Comment: You cannot access the address in User space. See [User space and system space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces#user-space-and-system-space).

Comment: @Caleth fair enough, unconventional C++ then :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and the line `printf_s("%d\n", fileObj->Type);` throws a `read access violation` exception. The address of `fileObj` is `0xFFFF800D0F4C3940`.

[image: exception]

According to [Virtual address spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces):

> The range of virtual addresses that is available to a process is known
> as the process's virtual address space. Each [user-mode process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/user-mode-and-kernel-mode#user-mode) has its
> own private virtual address space.
>
> - A 32-bit process typically has a virtual address space within the    2-gigabyte range 0x00000000 through 0x7FFFFFFF.
> - A 64-bit process on 64-bit Windows has a virtual address space within    the 128-terabyte range 0x000'00000000 through
>   0x7FFF'FFFFFFFF.

and

> Code running in user mode can access user space but not system space.
> This restriction prevents user-mode code from reading or altering
> protected operating system data structures.

Attempt to access the address larger than `0x7FFF'FFFFFFFF` will cause a read access violation.